# Prevent jquery-validate from using the title attribute as an error message?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-validate

Jquery validate uses the `title` attribute as the error message.  I use the `title` attribute to provide user tooltips, but I don't want it to replace validation error messages.

In this complete example, I've set the **Last Name** field to have a `title` attribute while leaving the **First Name** field without a `title` attribute.  When the form submits, the **First Name** field properly displays the error message - "*This field is required.*", while the **Last Name** field displays the contents of the `title` attribute.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" id="mainform">

        Last Name
        <input name="LastName" type="text" required="required" title="I don't want this to appear on my form" />
        <br />

        First Name
        <input name="FirstName" type="text" required="required" />
        <br />

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

    </form>

    <script>
        $("#mainform").validate();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to prevent jquery-validate from using the `title` attribute as an error message?

Comment: [Read the documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#toptions):  `ignoreTitle: true`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/e6ndm/

Doc: http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#toptions

Rest should fit your need `:)`

```
$("#mainform").validate({
    ignoreTitle: true
});
```